# How to avoid code-duplication with open/close database use-case (context management)?

Tags: go

Just getting started with Go and I'm wondering about the following situation:

I have a pretty simple codebase where I simply want to open/close a database connection and execute a simple query. I can do this as follows (just showing the important bits here):

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func (db *Database) ExecQueryA() {
    dbConn, err := sql.Open("postgres", db.psqlconn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer dbConn.Close()

    _, err = db.Exec(...
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The above idea works fine, but what if I want to write x more of these functions, I do not want to duplicate this part:

```golang
dbConn, err := sql.Open("postgres", db.psqlconn)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer dbConn.Close()
```

At the start of each function (i.e. I want to avoid code duplication). In python I would write a context manager for this, I.e. I would use a `with ..` statement which would open and close the database connection for me. When using Go, what is the best way to avoid code duplication in this use case?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to call `Open` & `Close` for every `Exec`? As per [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) "the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB." ([this example](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#example-package-OpenDBService) may help).

Comment: This is a good resource when starting out with SQL on Go, common pitfalls and good practice things - like not calling sql.Open everywhere : [http://go-database-sql.org/](http://go-database-sql.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Brits points out in the comment to your question, the `*sql.DB` does not need to be open and closed every time you intend to use it. Instead a single shared instance of `*sql.DB`, [`Open`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open)ed once at the launch of your app, is a common and recommended practice.

> ... the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary
> to close a DB.

Note that [`*sql.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB) is not *a* connection, instead, it is a pool that manages multiple connections, opens as many as necessary (and possible), keeps idle ones around if necessary, frees them if unnecessary, etc. And most of all, it is *safe for concurrent use*.

> DB is a database handle representing a pool of zero or more underlying
> connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

---

To answer your actual question, one pattern to reduce the repetition of obtaining-and-releasing resources is to pass a function literal to a wrapper function:

```golang
func (db *Database) run(f func(c *sql.DB)) {
    c, err := sql.Open("postgres", db.psqlconn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    
    f(c)
}

func (db *Database) ExecQueryA() {
    db.run(func(c *sql.DB) {
        _, err := c.Exec(...
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thx. that is great info! The GoLang `sql.Open` doc (https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open ) is not so straight forward about the connection pool unfortunately (altought it makes total sense), a good ref. for others coming here: http://go-database-sql.org/connection-pool.html